# Adware issue on Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

I have written about this issue on msdn forum and I was asked to use some adware cleaner tools to deal with this problem. 
Well I scanned my PC with multiple adware cleaners and that lead to some Wifi issues which I resolved afterwards.
I also had to uninstall many of my softwares.

umm right now, the ads are still there and they appear more frequently on my browser "Chrome".

Yeah, there is a small written thing at the bottom of every ad 'powered by cloudget'.
I am not allowed to post  snapshot.

I'd appreciate any sort of help in this regard.

Comment: Go to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome and delete all data. AppData is hidden folder in your user folder so you'll need to enable 'Show hidden files and folders' in explorer. Also if you're signed in to Chrome, your Chrome will sync your extensions so you'll need to clear them from your Chrome account to...

Comment: @Davidenko okay, thank you. I will delete all the app data

Comment: So after deleting all the app data and losing my bookmarks, I am still seeing those ads. "powered by cloudget".
Thank you @Davidenko!

Comment: OMG, sorry I forgot to tell you to save your bookmarks :(

Comment: Well its okay now. Kindly let me know a way to get rid of those adwares. 
Honestly I am tired of seeing them. @Davidenko

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.fixyourbrowser.com/removal-instructions/remove-powered-cloudget-ads-removal-guide/?

Comment: @Davidenko Anti-Malware software from the above link you suggested worked pretty great and now there are absolutely no cloudget ads. Bundle of thanks. :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked!! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you are browsing using Google Chrome then to solve your problem download Ad-block or Ad-block-plus from the chrome web-store. 
Here's the link from where you can download it. :- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus/ookcoahhikhembadmoepbhiepkmbjija 
It's an add-on for Google chrome and is on chrome web-store so it is trustworthy and will not make any harm to your pc. Moreover, I am also using it and its good.